# Steps to Create a Signed Desktop App for Windows 8?

Tags: desktop-application, signing, authenticode

I have a desktop application that I created for nopCommerce.  One of the features is to allow users to drag and drop images from windows explorer into my app, and the images are uploaded to the selected product.  In the past, Windows 7 and prior stopped them unless they disabled UAC, and that was fine with most users.  However in Windows 8 they can still disable UAC (really, really disable it with a reg setting) but not having UAC on breaks the Metro apps.  In testing I've tried running it as admin and that did not work.  Only disabling Uac in the Group Policy registry setting really worked.

I need to take the next step(s) and get my app Windows 8 compatible, obviously so they can use windows explorer drag and drop without having to disable/enable UAC all the time.  I've done a lot of research and I think I need to:

1. Purchase a code signing certificate
2. Sign my code using SignTool
3. Sign the Installer just to be safe (??)
4. Include a manifest that describes the required permissions...what should that look like?
5. Is there anything else I need to do when I build the app using VS2012?

Am I on the right track?....I'm pretty much at a loss on this!   Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This is the certification requirements, a big long list. plz make sure your app complies with these.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh749939.aspx